# jQuery in a web request from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, scheduled-tasks

The PHP website I'm developing has a manually initiated process that relies on jQuery AJAX calls so that the user can be updated on the progress of the process. Now the site owners want this process to be run automatically at a set time every night.

I have figured out how to use Windows Task Scheduler to call the PHP page that kicks off the process, but after several tests, there is no indication that the AJAX calls are being made. My theory is that no client-side scripting is being processed because no browser being opened by the Task Scheduler.

But I have Googled this extensively and I have been unable to find anything that says definitively that we can not use jQuery, javascript, or AJAX in a process initiated by Task Scheduler.

Does anyone know if it is possible? If so, can you give me an idea of how? Does anyone know if it is impossible? If so can you point to some authority that I can show my boss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What process have you scheduled to run automatically? There has to be some environment to run that JavaScript/jQuery code, or else, as you just mentioned, there'll be no "execution" at all. Maybe, you need to use something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to get the job done. But overall, why don't you schedule a task to run the "actual" job at hand instead of posting a request to a web application?

Comment: Mehdi, the idea is to minimize development time by calling the manual process that already exists. The manual page has headers and menus and what-not along with a div that displays the progress of the process. The manual process queries the database to get the records that need to be processed, then uses jQuery to make an AJAX call to a page that processes the first record. When the AJAX call is returned, an update is displayed in the div, and the AJAX function is called for the next record, etc.

Comment: So you have to use a "headless" browser to send the web request.

Comment: I know you don't like this but still I believe you need to split the code you already have into different modules/services so that each of which can be invoked separately. This way, you can reuse the same code both within the Web App, and when needed, from the scheduled task. If you don't do that, you have to use a headless browser so that those JS/jQuery codes get executed. This however makes your current architecture even more complicated...

Comment: Oh, I like it just fine. I need to convince the people holding the purse strings that we can't do what they want with the existing code.